# Dynamic from in $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, node-mongodb-native

I am trying to see if i can change the **from** in the **$lookup** or rearrange my query to somehow retrieve from three potential collections. So far i have managed to set up the query like so:

```
const search = db.collection("search");

search.aggregate([
  {
    '$match': {
      'id_int': 0
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      '_id': 0, 
      'collection': 1, 
      'id_int': 1
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'arxiv', 
      'localField': 'id_int', 
      'foreignField': 'id_int', 
      'as': 'arxiv'
    }
  }
], function(err, cursor) ... )
```

The **$match** and then **$project** pipeline stages return a result with the following properties:

```
collection:"arxiv"
id_int:0
```

The collection value will always be one of three arxiv, crossref or pmc_test. Therefore i'd like my **$lookup from** to use this property value programmatically as opposed having it hard coded.

```
'$lookup': {
   'from': 'arxiv' or 'crossref' or 'pmc_test', // Dynamic based on result
   ...
}
```

Thanks

**Edit**

id_int will get passed in and collection will not, thats why a query is made to the search collection.

Comment: So you wanted to read from either one of collection & the name comes from a field? I doubt if it's possible to do

Comment: any query or schema rearrangements you might recommend?

Comment: As you are describing, it's not possible due to MongoDB limitation (from expects string value). Take a look `$facet` operator, maybe it's helpful fo your usecase

Comment: Based on the (changing) `collection` value, you can use three _facets_; one for each of the  'arxiv' or 'crossref' or 'pmc_test'. Each facet (of the [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html)) will have a `$match` (matching the `collection` with one of the three values), followed by the `$lookup` with the `from` value matching for that facet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly this is not possible currently, there is an open feature request on it [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22497) so you can keep track of it if you wish.

Right now thought you have two options.

1. Split your call into 2 queries and add that bit of logic to your code, which is what i personally recommend.
2. Use this aggregate which looks up all 3 collections:

```
search.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            'id_int': 0
        }
    },
    {
        '$project': {
            '_id': 0,
            'collection': 1,
            'id_int': 1
        }
    },
    {
        "$facet": {
            "arxiv": [
                {
                    "$lookup": {
                        "from": "arxiv",
                        "localField": "id_int",
                        "foreignField": "id_int",
                        "as": "arxiv"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "crossref": [
                {
                    "$lookup": {
                        "from": "crossref",
                        "localField": "id_int",
                        "foreignField": "id_int",
                        "as": "crossref"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "pmc_test": [
                {
                    "$lookup": {
                        "from": "pmc_test",
                        "localField": "id_int",
                        "foreignField": "id_int",
                        "as": "pmc_test"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "newRoot": [
                {
                    "k": "$collection",
                    "v": {
                        "$cond": [
                            {
                                "$eq": [
                                    "$collection",
                                    "arxiv"
                                ]
                            },
                            "$arxiv",
                            {
                                "$cond": [
                                    {
                                        "$eq": [
                                            "$collection",
                                            "crossref"
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "$crossref",
                                    "$pmc_test"
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "k": "collection", "v": "$collection"
                },
                {
                    "k": "id_int", "v": "$id_int"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$replaceRoot": {
            "newRoot": {
                "$arrayToObject": {
                    "$concatArrays": "$newRoot"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

As you might have noticed the pipeline isn't exactly sexy, if you don't care about the field name in the end result you can dump most of it.